# How do I create a user using OAuth2?

Tags: django, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, tastypie

I am using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) with a [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, and the [Django-OAuth-Toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit), and a [Tastypie authentication for the Django-OAuth-Toolkit](https://github.com/orcasgit/django-tastypie-oauth/blob/master/tastypie_oauth/authentication.py).

**Disclaimer:** There is a chance I am totally wrong about all of this. If so, please correct me and guide me towards the less ignorant.

**Main Question:** How do I create users securely?

**My Understanding:**

- In order to `get` or `post`, the client needs a token.
- In order to get a token, [they need to login](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html#authorize-the-application).
- In order to login they need a user account.
- In order to make an account they need token.
- *In order to make an account they need to login?*

I am left in a struggle trying to figure this out. Do I make it when the client tries to make an account it does not need OAuth2? Or is there a way to use OAuth2 without a login that only lets the client create accounts?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in order to make an account you don't need a token, Signup using the normal flow, and on login request authenticate the user and give the token for further communication.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is No, OAuth2 is usually meant for authorisation which in turn needs authentication.

So for creating account you cannot use Oauth, you have to use normal flow , setup account and then you can use OAuth to gain access token.